# My htaccess file isn't working for URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change something like

```
http://x.com/genre.php?type=action 
to:
http://x.com/genre/action
```

or

```
http://x.com/genre.php?type=action&arg=tv
to
http://x.com/genre/action?tv
```

I've tried several methods but none of them have been working for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^genre.php?type=*$ /genre/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I think I'm going about this completely wrong, can someone shine light to the situation?

My current htaccess file simply removes .php from the end of files with .php successfully which I took from some source on the internet.

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/$ /genre.php?action=$1 [L]
```